# TextArea text is not getting set when in another state

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, stage

The TextArea.text value is not getting set or staying set. This happens when I have a transition and that uses a Rotate3D and there are two transitions. With one transition it works. With two transitions (the return transition) it doesn't. So in the case below I have a transition from "note" to "list". If I add a transition from "list" to "note" then the behavior occurs. BUT if I put the textArea (note) in both states then it works correctly (ie incluedIn="note,list" works)!

```
<s:Group id="noteGroup" includeIn="note">

    <s:TextArea id="normalTextArea" />

</s:Group>


<s:transitions>
    <s:Transition fromState="note" toState="list"
                  autoReverse="false">
        <s:Sequence target="{this}"
                    duration="{duration}" >
            <s:Rotate3D angleYFrom="0" angleYTo="90" 
                        autoCenterTransform="true" 
                        applyChangesPostLayout="true"
                        />
            <s:SetAction target="{noteGroup}" property="visible" />
            <s:RemoveAction target="{noteGroup}" />
            <s:AddAction target="{listGroup}"/>
            <s:Rotate3D angleYFrom="-90" angleYTo="0" 
                        autoCenterTransform="true" 
                        applyChangesPostLayout="true"/>
        </s:Sequence>
    </s:Transition>

    <s:Transition fromState="list" toState="note"
                  autoReverse="false"
                  >
        <s:Sequence target="{this}" duration="{duration}" >

            <s:Rotate3D angleYFrom="0" angleYTo="-90" 
                        effectStart="trace('rotateStart')"
                        duration="250" 
                        autoCenterTransform="true"
                        applyChangesPostLayout="true" />

            <s:AddAction target="{noteGroup}"
                        effectStart="trace('add notes action')"/>
            <s:SetAction target="{noteGroup}" property="visible" />
            <s:RemoveAction target="{listGroup}" 
                        effectStart="trace('remove lists action')"/>

            <s:Rotate3D angleYFrom="90" angleYTo="0" 
                        effectStart="trace('rotateStart 2')"
                        duration="250" 
                        autoCenterTransform="true"
                        applyChangesPostLayout="true" />

        </s:Sequence>
    </s:Transition>

</s:transitions>
```

~~ **UPDATE** ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

A work around I mentioned is to include the textarea in both states and then set the visible to false in the state that it was not originally included in:

```
<s:Group id="noteGroup" 
         includeIn="note,list"
         visible.list="false">

    <s:TextArea id="normalTextArea" />

</s:Group>
```

~~ **UPDATE** ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Setting the value later (after the transition) works (thanks Flextras) but the text is not visible until I place the cursor in the textarea.

List change handler code:

```
protected function list1_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void {
    content = (list.selectedItem as Note).content;
    currentState = "note";

    setTimeout(setText,1000);
}

private function setText():void {
    normalTextArea.text = content; // works but only on clicking into the textarea
}
```

THIS DOES NOT WORK:

```
        protected function list1_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void {
            content = (list.selectedItem as Note).content;
            normalTextArea.text = content;
            trace('1 text ='+normalTextArea.text); // contains content
            currentState = "note";
            normalTextArea.text = content;
            trace('2 text ='+normalTextArea.text); // contains content

            setTimeout(setText,1000);
        }

        // scenario 1
        private function setText():void {
            normalTextArea.text = content; // clicking into textarea it is empty
        }

        // scenario 2
        private function setText():void {
            normalTextArea.text = ""; // this does work but
            normalTextArea.text = content; // you have to click into textarea
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean you're entering a value in the normalTextArea which is not getting stored as you transition from one state to the other?  I'm more intimate w/ the MX state functionality; what that did was remove the child when we went to a state where it didn't exist.  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/states/RemoveChild.html Then it Addchild in the reverse http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/states/AddChild.html . I would expect properties to not change in transitions. Try storing the value b/f changing states; and set it after

Comment: That's correct. In code, before setting the new state, currentstate="note" I set the normalTextArea.text = newContent. But that value wasn't sticking. So it seems to be restoring the textarea to it's former state. Setting the value at a later time works but oddly enough you have to click into the text area for the new value to be visible.